# ARC releases my object somewhere in Apple's UI library

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I have a local variable `UINavigationConroller *nav`. Not 10 lines after it's declared, within the same method, it is passed to `[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil]` (`self` is a `UIViewController`). I know passing `nil` here is OK because [the documentation says it is](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:).

Just before passing it in, everything's fine. However, while it's in there ARC deallocates it and the app soon crashes when something in Apple's UI library calls `[UINavigationController isKindOfClass:]`, presumably on my `nav` object. Here's the console output:

```
2015-03-20 13:33:50.729 Now[9183:3980870] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <MyViewController: 0x125042200>.
2015-03-20 13:33:50.730 Now[9183:3980870] *** -[UINavigationController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x12601c6e0
```

I've been stepping in, out, and through this class and assembly code for a couple days, Googling as much as I can, and can't seem to fix it. My only solution left was to call `[nav retain]` just before `presentViewController`, and `[nav release]` immediately after, but ARC forbids this. This is a huge, old project so **we can't just turn off ARC.**

**How do I keep `nav` form being deallocated before it's done being used?**

### Update:

---

I've inspected this using the Zombie profiler. I've discovered that it is indeed a `UINavigationController`, and is indeed being deallocated within UIKit:

[image: A screenshot of the Zombie profiler]

The most telling thing is the top two lines, which show it going from 960B on allocation, immediately to 0:

[image: A screenshot of the top 2 frames in the Zombie proviler, hilighting the immediate nullification]

I'm this looks atypical, and throws up red flags for me.

Comment: The first log message implies that you are presenting it from a controller that isn't in your view controller hierarchy.  Are you trying to present it in `MyViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method or from a child view controller?

Comment: Are you sure that `0x12601c6e0` is the address of `nav`?

Comment: very nice points, will check them soon

Comment: Have you tried the Zombie instrument to look at the retain-release history of this object?

Comment: @newacct yes, I am trying that.

Comment: Screenshot added, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved. It turns out that back when this codebase was first written, it used a "stashing" system, that would hold any modal `UIViewController` in a field and then dismiss it. When needed again, it would present that stashed modal and `nil`ify the stash variable.

The problem comes in how I was handling things, not knowing about this system. In directly presenting or dismissing the modal, I was inadvertently setting up a situation in which this system presented a zombie `UINavigationController`. After using this system, it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:navCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you object is being released for some reason, then don't depend on it. Instead, depend on the window's root controller.

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description`.  Thanks

Comment: Why should I try that?

Comment: If you object is being released for some reason, then don't depend on it. Instead, depend on the window's root controller.

Comment: I've tried this, and it seems to have changed nothing. The error still occurs just the same. Perhaps the root view controller is the thing being deallocated?